# How some defect types can cause particle-hole symmetry breaking in graphene?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, symmetry-breaking, graphene

According to literature, some defect types (e.g. Stone-Wales) produce hopping between the same sublattice (e.g. A to A), which has been pointed out as the reason for particle-hole symmetry breaking. Next nearest neighbour couplings have also a similar effect. However, I couldn't find a document explaining the underlying mechanism of this breaking. For example, statements like "it causes shift in Fermi level" does not explain why the spectrum is not the mirror image w/ respect to the new Fermi level.

I don't understand how hopping between same sublattices can cause particle-hole symmetry breaking? What are the physical *and* mathematical reasons/mechanisms of it?

Comment: "between the *same* sublattice" or "between sublattice*s*"?
Perhaps you will find this interesting - it is not about Stone-Wales, but it could serve as a departing point to look for references and citations: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/77/27006/pdf

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the reference. I mean "the same sublattice, like A to A or B to B".

Comment: I am not quite sure why these defects would cause *particle-hole symmetry breaking*, if no other bads/subbands involved. The defects break some of the lattice symmetries and therefore may cause opeing of a gap, and the particle-hole symmetry would be broken, if the Fermi level, for some reason, is not in the middle of the gap.